# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#show, Couldn't find Post with 'id'=#

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm coding a simple blog with posts and I can't seem to be able to get the code right for going back to the index page after "destroying" a post. I'm following this tutorial and I'm stuck around minute 14
[Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VJ6c311Qr_Q&list=PL23ZvcdS3XPK9Y4DRU-BiJtiY5L_QhUUq&index=13)
I'm working with ruby 3.0.3 and Rails 7.0.3, the error I'm getting is the following:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guJBp.png)

Below are the relevant pieces of code:

- Controller

  ```
    class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    def index
    end

    def new
        @post = Post.new    
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new post_params

        if @post.save
            redirect_to @post, notice: "post has been saved"
        else
            render 'new', notice: "Post could NOT be saved"
        end
    end

    def show

    end

    def edit

    end

    def update
        if @post.update post_params
        redirect_to @post, notice: "Your article has been updated"
    else
        render 'edit'
    end

    end

    def destroy
        @post.destroy
        respond_to do posts_path
    end
    end

    private

    def  post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
    end

    def find_post
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    end

    end
  ```
- Show (view)

  ```
    <%= @post.title %><br>
    <%= @post.content %>

     <br>
     <br>

     <%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(@post) %>
     <%= link_to "Delete", post_path(@post), data: { :turbo_method => :delete, 
     :turbo_confirm => 'Are you sure?'} %>
  ```
- Routes

  ```
     Rails.application.routes.draw do
      resources :posts

     end
  ```
- Migration

  ```
    class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
     def change
      create_table :posts do |t|
       t.string :title
       t.text :content

       t.timestamps
      end
      end
      end
  ```

I would deeply appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```rb
# DELETE /posts/1
def destroy
  @post.destroy
  redirect_to posts_url, notice: "Post was successfully destroyed."
end
```

This  *destroy* method works with `button_to`:

```
<%= button_to "Destroy post", post_path(@post), method: :delete %>
```

If you want to use `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to "Destroy post", post_path(@post), data: { turbo_method: :delete } %>
```

redirect status has to be changed to `status: :see_other`:

```rb
# DELETE /posts/1
def destroy
  @post.destroy
  redirect_to posts_url, status: :see_other, notice: "Post was successfully destroyed."
end
```

---

Turbo *DELETE* request work in progress: *https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/issues/259*

Answer (score 0):

When you didn't find a record, is no way to destroy it. Rewrite post finder to:

```rb
def find_post
  @post = Post.find_by(id: params[:id])
end
```

I replaced `respond_to` with `redirect_to`, but it is not a principal:

```rb
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
  ensure
    redirect_to posts_path
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea Sergio, unfortunately, I still get the same error with "redirect_to"

Comment: I update my answer just a minute.

Comment: Your answer did make some changes, now I get a different error referring to my view page (show) that reads:

NoMethodError in Posts#show
Showing C:/blog/app/views/posts/show.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #1):
1
<%= @post.title %><br>
<%= @post.content %>

<br>
<br>